# How to change math accent heights?

Tags: spacing, accents

When I use the `lmodern` package (which is always), math accents `tilde` and `bar` do not change the character height (w.r.t. `\left` and `\right`). However, the `hat` accent makes the character taller. The file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
$$
\left( \tilde A \right)
\left( \hat A \right)
\left( \bar A \right)
$$
\end{document}
```

renders as

[image]

How can I make the `hat` accent behave like `tilde` and `bar`?

PS. If I don't use `lmodern` it falls back to Computer Modern and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Use manual sizing of brackets with `\bigl` and the like.

Comment: Delimiters come in *discrete* sizes, so, when the material between them exceeds a certain threshold, the next size is employed. It's not that `\tilde` and `\bar` do not change the height, it's rather that the threshold is not exceeded. In most cases, `\left` and `\right` are *not* needed and in general fences are not required to cover the entire vertical extension of the material between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiters come in discrete sizes, so, when the material between them exceeds a certain threshold, the next size is employed. It's not that `\tilde` and `\bar` do not change the height, it's rather that the threshold is not exceeded.

In your examples, `\big` size is chosen with `\tilde` and `\bar`, but `\Big` size turns up with `\hat`.

In most cases, \left and \right are not needed and in general fences are not required to cover the entire vertical extension of the material between them. Look at the output of the following example, where also a `\rhat` (*reduced* hat) is defined (but not recommended).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\shat}[1]{%
  \smash{\hat{#1}}%
  \vphantom{\bar{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

No change:
\[
\left( \tilde{A} \right)
\left( \hat{A} \right)
\left( \bar{A} \right)
\]

Change:
\[
\left( \tilde{A} \right)
\left( \shat{A} \right)
\left( \bar{A} \right)
\]

Better:
\[
(\tilde{A})
(\hat{A})
(\bar{A})
\]

\end{document}
```

In my opinion, the last example is the one to be followed.

Note: `$$` should never be used in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The paired delimiters come from a third macro, so I can not change that. I ended up redefining `\hat` has `\shat`. Maybe later... I will smash all accents. :)